# In a PostgreSQL db with PostGIS how can I sort a geometry column based on (number of bytes or points) in column?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am new to GIS and PostGIS. I have an existing legacy database table with millions of rows and a geometry column. It has a mix of points like this:

[image]

I wish to sort the rows based the size of the geometry column.

I suspect that someone put a map of the US in one of the rows and it doesn't belong in this table. I want the biggest geometry sorted to the top.

I've experimented with length and ST_Transform but I am getting the following error:

[image]

I plan on using tablePlus and QGIS to help examine the geometry visually once I find the row(s).

Comment: I did not capture it, but the geometry column also contains simple POINT(x,y) rows.

Comment: try using `st_area`

Comment: Better, use `ST_NPoints`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @geozelot for the answer.

```
SELECT entity_type, ST_NPoints(geometry) as NPoints, geometry
FROM location 
WHERE geometry IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ST_NPoints(geometry) DESC
LIMIT 10000;
```